# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains' (Spring Securiy)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I an using Spring framework 4.0.3.RELEASE. I try every solutions in all articles on stackoverflow and non of them works for me.
I see this error:

```
Jul 16, 2015 9:37:11 PM org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader initWebApplicationContext
SEVERE: Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.filterChains': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0' while setting bean property 'sourceList' with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:684)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:403)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0' while setting constructor argument with key [5]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0' while setting bean property 'authenticationManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.config.authentication.AuthenticationManagerFactoryBean#0': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authenticationManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0' while setting constructor argument with key [0]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0' while setting bean property 'userDetailsService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.provisioning.JdbcUserDetailsManager#0': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:157)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:140)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 26 more
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets 
        and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/panel**" access="hasRole('USER')" />

        <!-- access denied page -->
        <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />

        <intercept-url pattern="/panel/**" access="hasRole('USER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
        <!-- enable csrf protection -->
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider>
            <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select username,password,enabled from users where username=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select u1.username, u2.role from users u1, user_roles u2 where u1.user_id = u2.user_id and u1.username =?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

</beans:beans>
```

Could somebody explain what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the error

```
NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'dataSource' is defined
```

You have to define the `dataSource`.

Comment: I defined dataSource on servlet-contex.xml

Comment: Check it if it is visible from the spring security context. It seams not. Or check if the name is with a different camel case

Comment: how can I make it visible for spring security?

Comment: Spring Application contexts are hierarchical. The context loader listener bootstraps your AC and makes them available 'globally'. Probably you have defined the dataSource in the context at level of the single DispatcherServlet not the global context.

Comment: I have also defined the bean in servlet-context.xml file.. facing the same problem.. How do I fix this.. How can I make this bean visible to spring-security.xml file. Please help